# How to find IN list vs compare line by line Join ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I need some help on figuring the solution to this in Oracle SQL.

I have the 2 tables below the Oppty Table and the Acc Table

| Acc_ID | Oppty ID | Product1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | JJJ | apples |
| 123 | ZZZ | oranges |
| 567 | aaj | apples |
| 888 | UUU | berries |

| Acc_ID | Product2 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | apples |
| 123 | apples |
| 123 | oranges |
| 567 | bananas |
| 567 | grapes |
| 567 | apples |
| 888 | oranges |

And then I do a LEFT JOIN on Oppty.ACC_ID = Acc.ACC_ID, so I get the following table with an added calculated field (CF) if product1 = product2 then TRUE else FALSE

| Acc_ID | Oppty ID | Product1 | Product2 | CF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | JJJ | apples | apples | TRUE |
| 123 | JJJ | apples | apples | TRUE |
| 123 | JJJ | apples | oranges | FALSE |
| 123 | zzz | oranges | apples | FALSE |
| 123 | zzz | oranges | apples | FALSE |
| 123 | zzz | oranges | oranges | TRUE |
| 567 | aaj | apples | bananas | FALSE |
| 567 | aaj | apples | grapes | FALSE |
| 567 | aaj | apples | apples | TRUE |
| 888 | UUU | berries | oranges | FALSE |

Right now I am comparing line by line where Product1t != Product2 is FALSE, however I want the results to look at each Acc_ID to see if there a Product Match and if so then TRUE, basically I am trying to do an IN statement dynamically?

For example in line 3 where Product1 is apples and Acc_ID is 123, it is currently showing FALSE because apples != oranges, however, I want it to look at all
Product2 under the same Acc_ID (123) and spit out TRUE if there's a match - so since there are other apples under Product2 for Acc_ID 123 it would spit out TRUE.

The new table should look like this, thank you for your help!

| Acc_ID | Oppty ID | Product1 | Product2 | CF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | JJJ | apples | apples | TRUE |
| 123 | JJJ | apples | apples | TRUE |
| 123 | JJJ | apples | oranges | TRUE |
| 123 | zzz | oranges | apples | TRUE |
| 123 | zzz | oranges | apples | TRUE |
| 123 | zzz | oranges | oranges | TRUE |
| 567 | aaj | apples | bananas | TRUE |
| 567 | aaj | apples | grapes | TRUE |
| 567 | aaj | apples | apples | TRUE |
| 888 | UUU | berries | oranges | FALSE |

Comment: "Right now I am comparing line by line " Where?  You need to show the code.

Comment: just to make sure. if there's one match under an id you want it all to say true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use below solution for your purpose.

```sql
select 
  op.Acc_ID
, op.Oppty_ID
, op.Product1
, ac.Product2
, CASE WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM Acc ac2 
            WHERE ac2.Acc_ID = op.Acc_ID 
            AND ac2.Product2 = op.Product1
            ) 
       THEN 'TRUE' 
       ELSE 'FALSE' 
  END cf
from Oppty op
left join Acc ac 
    on op.Acc_ID = ac.Acc_ID
ORDER BY op.Acc_ID, op.Product1 
;
```

[demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9520b32bbe0bb5293100c25ea78c609f)

Comment: Thank you this worked for me, quick question what is the point of the AND ROWNUM < 2  line?

Comment: Actually you don't need to rownum < 2, you can remove it. I am used to using it because in my working environment (very old version of oracle) they disabled oracle optimizer statistics and many others things. So we need to force manually Oracle stop excuting a "where exists" subquery as soon as it finds the first match.

Comment: Sorry to bother but I was wondering if you could help explain why the results change if I switch the FROM table in the case statement see code below:  CASE WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM Oppty op2
            WHERE op2.Acc_ID = ac.Acc_ID 
            AND  op2.Product1 = ac.Product2
            ) 
       THEN 'TRUE' 
       ELSE 'FALSE' 
  END cf

Answer (score 0):

```
select  "Acc_ID"    
       ,"Oppty ID"  
       ,"Product1"
       ,"Product2"
       ,case count(case "Product1" when "Product2" then 1 end) over(partition by "Acc_ID") when 0 then 'False' else 'True' end  as CF
from Oppty o left join Acc a using("Acc_ID")
```

| Acc_ID | Oppty ID | Product1 | Product2 | CF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | JJJ | apples | apples | True |
| 123 | ZZZ | oranges | apples | True |
| 123 | JJJ | apples | apples | True |
| 123 | ZZZ | oranges | apples | True |
| 123 | JJJ | apples | oranges | True |
| 123 | ZZZ | oranges | oranges | True |
| 567 | aaj | apples | bananas | True |
| 567 | aaj | apples | grapes | True |
| 567 | aaj | apples | apples | True |
| 888 | UUU | berries | oranges | False |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e19f37ae41bcc5ddf6409652a185e2ba&hide=15)

Comment: yes. just play with it in the fiddle and see how i structured it.

Comment: For example let's say there is a Product3 and Product4, and I wanted to do this one more level, so if Product1 != Product2 is still false, but if Product1 = Product2 is TRUE (partitioning by ACC_ID) then look at Product3 = Product4, and If Product3 = Product4 (also partitioning by ACC_ID) then TRUE, else FALSE?

Comment: The way I've done it is to mark every time the condition happens `case "Product1" when "Product2" then 1 end`. After that I counted by `Acc_ID` . If the condition happened it would be more than 1 for every row per `Acc_ID`. After that I said that if it's more than 0 then true (else false). You can change the first condition to whatever you need and it would still work.